# Can I disable autoloading associations in ActiveRecord?

Tags: rails-activerecord

Imagine a Rails application with authors and books. On the books index page, we list each book with its author, like `book.author.name`.

One of two things will happen:

1. If `book.author` is not yet loaded, ActiveRecord will query the database to find the author
2. If `book.author` was preloaded (eg `Book.includes(:author)`), the objects will be fetched from memory

In scenario #1, **the view causes an N+1 query** - every time it tries to render another book, it has to do another `SELECT * from authors where author_id = $1` (using the `books.author_id`).

This is bad for performance and often hard to track down. It would be much better (IMHO) if the controller loaded all the data needed by the view, and the view could not trigger queries at all.

**Is there a way to disable ActiveRecord's "on demand" loading of associations?** In other words, to make scenario #1 raise an exception saying something like "association not available, please see documentation on preloading associations"?

Comment: JEG2 pointed out on Twitter: "I believe the reasoning for lazy queries was to support caching. Queries happening in the views might never be reached." In my case, we're not using view cacheing, though, and avoiding N+1s would still make the cache misses faster. JEG2 agreed that this would be a neat option to have.

Comment: [Link to Twitter status](https://twitter.com/JEG2/status/700356114257301504) by James Edward Gray II (@JEG2) for posterity.